# OpenTripPlanner on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, opentripplanner

I am writing my bachelor's thesis on cross-platform applications for transport management systems.
The idea is to create a React Native application with OpenTripPlanner. I have found this - https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux and am wondering if it would be possible to open the example application through React Native on iOS and Android, possibly even web. I have opened it through WEB right now with the steps described and everything works perfectly.
Because I am very new at this, could any of you maybe help me with this? What would I need to do to open / develop the example application with React Native.
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its React project, its not possible to open this project in React Native.

The suggestion is to create the react native project and then implement the code by referring the code from example library.